# How do you enforce secure storage of Access Token by your Partner?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, openapi

In an Open API world, Tokens are the door key (issued to anyone with a valid Client Id and Secret). Tokens allow anybody who has them to access a resource. As such, they are as critical as passwords.

**Example**: A 3rd party Native App wanting to access your APIs. The app uses the 'Client Id and Secret' to request for an 'Access Token'. This access token to be used for subsequent API calls.

**Concern**: Usually 'Access Tokens' have a longer TTL. When they are stored in the Mobile App/Client mobile device and if someone gains access to it, they will be able to replay API calls from a different source using this access token and the API URI.

1. How do you prevent such replay attacks (when access token is
   compromised from the 3rd party app) for API calls ?
2. What secure practice do you follow to allow your consumers/clients
   to securely store the 'Access Tokens' ?

Answer (score 0):

> In an Open API world, Tokens are the door key (issued to anyone with a valid Client Id and Secret).

I like this analogy :)

### Tokens Importance

> Tokens allow anybody who has them to access a resource. As such, they are as critical as passwords.

Well even more critical, because they control access to the API, thus an automated attack with a stolen token can ex-filtrate all the data behinhd that API in a matter of seconds, minutes or hours, depending on the size of it, and if rate limiting or other type of defenses are in place or not, and this as a name, **Data Breach**, and fines under *GDPR* can be huge, and may even put the company out of business or in serious difficulties.

### Access Tokens with Refresh Tokens

> Example: A 3rd party Native App wanting to access your APIs. The app uses the 'Client Id and Secret' to request for an 'Access Token'. This access token to be used for subsequent API calls.
>
> Concern: Usually 'Access Tokens' have a longer TTL. When they are stored in the Mobile App/Client mobile device and if someone gains access to it, they will be able to replay API calls from a different source using this access token and the API URI.

The access token should be at least short-lived, and the client, mobile app or web app, should never be the ones requesting it to be issued, instead their respective back-ends should be the ones requesting it to the OAUTH provider, and use the refresh token mechanism to keep issuing short lived tokens, that should be in the range of a few minutes. This approach limits the time a compromised token can be reused by malicious requests.

So I would recommend you to switch to use refresh tokens, that will keep the access tokens short lived while refresh tokens can be long lived, but in the hours range, not days, weeks or years.

Example of refresh tokens flow:

[image: Refresh tokens flow]

**Sourced from:** [Mobile API Security Techniques - part 2](https://blog.approov.io/mobile-api-security-techniques-part-2#shorten-token-lifetimes)

> **NOTE:** While the above graphic belongs to a series of articles written in the context of mobile APIs, they have a lot of information that is also valid for APIs serving web apps and third party clients.

By using the refresh tokens approach, when a client request fails due to an expired short lived access token, then the client needs to request a new short lived access token.

The important bit here is that the refresh token should not be sent to the browser or mobile app, only the short lived access token can be sent, therefore your third party clients must kept refresh tokens private, aka in their backends, therefore they MUST NOT send refresh tokens from javascript or their mobile app, instead any renewal of the short lived access tokens MUST BE delegated to their backends.

This is a good improvement, but this only identifies **who** is making the request, not **what** is making it, therefore your APIs continue without being able to totally trust in the request they receive as coming from trusted sources.

Oh wait a bit... **who** and **what** is getting me confused. Well your aren't the only one, and this is indeed a common misconception among developers.

#### The difference between **who** and **what** is accessing the API server.

This is discussed in more detail in [this article](/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) I wrote, where we can read:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?
>
> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

If the quoted text is not enough for you to understand the differences, then please go ahead and read the entire section of the article, because without this being well understood you are prone to apply less effective security measures in your API server and clients.

### API Replay Attacks

> How do you prevent such replay attacks (when access token is compromised from the 3rd party app) for API calls ?

Well this is a very though problem to solve, because your API needs to know **what** is making the request, and it seems that now is only able to know the request was made in the behalf of some **who**.

For a more in depth approach on mitigating API replay attacks you go and read the section *Mitigate Replay Attacks* from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768795/how-to-secure-rest-api-from-replay-attacks-with-parameter-manipulation/60773987#60773987) I gave in another question:

> So you could have the client creating an HMAC token with the request url, user authentication token, your temporary token, and the time stamp that should be also present in a request header. The server would then grab the same data from the request and perform it's own calculation of the HMAC token, and only proceed with the request if it's own result matches the one for the HMAC token header in the request.
>
> For a practical example of this in action you can read part 1 and part 2 of [this blog series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-shipfast) about API protection techniques in the context of a mobile app, that also features a web app impersonating the mobile app.

It has some code examples for the HMAC implementation, so I really recommend you take a look into, but bear in mind that HMAC only makes it a little more difficult to crack, not impossible.

So this is a very hard problem to solve when the access token belongs to a web app, but it's doable in the case of a mobile app that uses a Mobile App Attestation solution, and this is described in [this section](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-protect-against-certificate-pinning-bypassing#mobile-app-attestation) of another article I wrote, from where I will quote the following text:

> In order to know what is sending the requests to the API server, a Mobile App Attestation service, at run-time, will identify with high confidence that your mobile app is present, has not been tampered/repackaged, is not running in a rooted device, has not been hooked into by an instrumentation framework(Frida, xPosed, Cydia, etc.), and is not the object of a [Man in the Middle Attack (MitM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). This is achieved by running an SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device it is running on.

For defending your API when used by mobile apps I recommend you to read the sections *Securing the API Server* and *A Possible Better Solution* from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I gave for the question **How to secure an API REST for mobile app? (if sniffing requests gives you the “key”)**. For web apps I recommend you to go and read the section *Web Application* from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435461/how-do-i-secure-a-rest-api/55569845#55569845) to the question *How do I secure a REST-API?*.

### Storing Access Tokens

> What secure practice do you follow to allow your consumers/clients to securely store the 'Access Tokens' ?

Well in web apps all it takes to extract any token is to hit `F12` and look for them, but in mobile apps you need to reverse engineer them.

For a mobile app you can stat by looking into the repository [android-hide-secrets](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/tree/master/app/src/main/cpp) to understand the several ways of hiding them, where the most effective is to use native `C` code, by leveraging [JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides) interfaces provided by Android. You can see more real use demo apps using this approach in the repo [currency-converter-demo](https://github.com/approov/currency-converter-demo) and the app for the [shipfast-api-protection-demo](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection). For example see [here](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/85997029436920a2499b2f5918c2076aaf0faf45/app/android/kotlin/ShipFast/app/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/shipfast/config/JniEnv.kt) how configuration is loaded from the [`C` code](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/85997029436920a2499b2f5918c2076aaf0faf45/app/android/kotlin/ShipFast/app/src/main/cpp/jni-env.cpp), by using [JNI/NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni) approach. But bear in mind that while this makes very hard to reverse engineer statically the mobile app binary to extract secrets, it doesn't provide any security from an attacker to go and use and instrumentation framework to hook into the code that returns the secret from the `C` code, or to perform a MitM attack to intercept the requests between the mobile app and the backend, thus getting hold of the secret you protect so well.

Mobile apps can solve this by using a Mobile App Attestation solution to not have any secrets at all in their code, therefore if you have read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I provided previously for defending your API when used by a mobile app, then you will be already more familiar with how a Mobile App Attestation works, and be able to better understand why you may want to have your clients using your API like this:

[image: Mobile App Attestation with Reverse Proxy]

So your API would be sitting along side the ones already in the *APIs* section, and the secret to access it is no longer in the public domain, instead is safely stored in the Reverse Proxy vault. To note that the green key is provided during runt time by the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud, and the mobile app doesn't know if is a valid or an invalid JWT token. If if you have done yet, please go and read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) I already provided to the other answer, so that you can understand in more detail how the attestation works.

In conclusion this approach doesn't benefit only your API, because it also improves the overall security for the mobile apps of your clients.

### GOING THE EXTRA MILE

As usual I am not able to finish a security related answer without recommending the excellent work of the OWASP foundation:

[The Web Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg):

> The OWASP Web Security Testing Guide includes a "best practice" penetration testing framework which users can implement in their own organizations and a "low level" penetration testing guide that describes techniques for testing most common web application and web service security issues.

[The Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.